# interact between Android Application and ADB

Tags: android, adb

I am running an application from ADB commands as follow:

adb shell am start -n com.example.someapp.app/.SimpleActivity

The main screen in this app will have two buttons, how can press one of these buttons from ADB Shell?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `adb shell input` command might work for you. You might need to have a rooted device to allow adb simulated touch input to work.

Here's a link to a blog containing a write up on adb input:
https://grymoire.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/remote-input-shell-scripts-for-your-android-device/

Answer (score 0):

You'd normally tap the button (if you know the coordinates):

```
adb shell input tap <x> <y>
```

To find coordinates, enable pointer location, then tap the button location on your device:

```
adb shell settings put system pointer_location 1
```

No need to root phone.

Tested on Android 10 API 29